# (?:\d[ -]*?){13,16} - confused with the priority that is given in matching the pattern to the given regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm confused why this pattern captures `4564-1234-4325-2146`, even though it has 19 digits including '-'
The above pattern only captures **4564-1234435-2146**-8
leaves the last hyphen and the digit 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It captures 13-16 digits, each followed by zero or more spaces or dashes (the `[ -]*?`). In other words, the `{13,16}` applies to the entire group `(?:\d[ -]*?)`. So, it could capture, for example, `1--2-3--4-5-6     7-----8-9-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-`. In your sample case, it captures these 16 chunks:

- 4
- 5
- 6
- 4-
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4-
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 5-
- 2
- 1
- 4
- 6